# How do you remember the British spelling of "Licence"?

Tags: british-english

As someone with Dyslexia, I always struggle with the US and UK variants of words. This one seems to be particularly difficult for me, so do you have any suggestions on how to remember the difference?

Comment: The verb in the UK is usually _license_. How will a 'BrE'-noun-spelling aide-memoire really help?

Comment: Spell it either way: it’ll give the nit-pickers something to get excited about.

Answer (score 1):

I find that visual reminders stick in my mind.

[image: How to remember the British spelling of Licence: England (en) has a c on both sides]

Comment: Where did this graphic come from? If you didn't make it yourself, then you need to give attribution.

Comment: Can you connect your mnemonic for the spelling of licence back to the word licence? So far, I see that England has two Cs (cenc), but not licence.

Comment: @YosefBaskin in BrE it is licence (noun) and license (verb), the same way as advice and advise where the pronunciation helps to remember. This answer doesn't help with that distinction though.

Comment: @Laurel my own idea and my own work.

Comment: Very good indeed. Bravo. I don't understand the meanness around here. Just add in the word BrE noun, and your own name in huge letters. :)